# The Pie Chart of Life on an Alternate Earth

Tags: fauna, worldbuilding-process

[image]

In this alternate Earth, all the species of fish, amphibian, reptile, mammal and bird combine to make up only 0.5% of all animal life on the planet (presented on the pie chart in blue.)  It doesn't sound much compared to the two or three percent back home, but it's still quite a lot of invertebrates!

As with back home, the other 80% of animals on this alternate Earth make up the arthropods.

[image]

By merging the two presented pies into one, how much would be reserved for the arthropods?

Comment: Are you asking what is 80% of 99.5%?

Comment: @MattBowyer  That's right.

Comment: I don't even know what category to close this question as. Maybe we need a trolling category. Off-topic will have to do.

Comment: @kingledion that wasn't very considerate, but it also was true. I am usually lenient was question, looking at their potential. But all he had to do was google 80% of 99.5%. Shameful.

Comment: @TinyTrEs-2b  "By merging the two presented pies into one, how much would be reserved for the arthropods?"  It's a show-don't-tell question.

Comment: @JohnWDailey it's not a good question, at best this is a mathmatics stack exchange question, not a worldbuilding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about worldbuilding. This is about using Microsoft Excel or <your favorite spreadsheet program>. Follow these steps to make the pie chart: http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Pie-Chart-in-Excel

Comment: Your getting lazy man. You take all that time to prepare these unending  lists of stuff but can't make a pie chart?

Comment: @Vincent  That attitude is uncalled for.  Nor does it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

80% of 99.5% is 79.6%

$$.80 * .995 = .796$$

[Google](https://www.google.com/#q=80%25+of+99.5%25)

Comment: Okay, so what does it look like?

Comment: @JohnWDailey: It looks like a number.

Comment: I can't see 79.6%.  I need to SEE the two pie charts meshed into one.

Comment: There's no percentages listed on your pie chart, so there's no way to blend the two pie charts. Put the number labels on there.